# Hiberanate 6.4 - JPA persitence unit not found. SAXParser issue with persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml, saxparseexception

Please advise or help with this error that I keep getting when running a jUnit in a simple JPA/Hibernate project. The entire setup is trivial because I want to ensure it is bare bones to isolate the issue first.

I am using Windows 11 Home, Java 17 SDK, Hibernate 6.4.0 and Maven 3.9.

Stacktrace is,

```
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.312 s <<< FAILURE! -- in come.lets.learn.AppTest
come.lets.learn.AppTest -- Time elapsed: 0.312 s <<< ERROR!
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at come.lets.learn.AppTest.setUpBeforeClass(AppTest.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:70)
    ..........
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    ..........
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    ...........
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56)
    ...........
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.close()" because "come.lets.learn.AppTest.emf" is null
        at come.lets.learn.AppTest.tearDownAfterClass(AppTest.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        .........
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Unexpected error parsing [file:/D:/Some/Path/DirectProject/my-java-app/target/test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:79)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 37; A pseudo attribute name is expected.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:262)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:474)
... 71 more
```

My persistence.xml(project-root/src/main/resources/META-INF) and jUnit look like below.

```
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemalocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence 
https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="perApp">
    <description>Sample Project</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="data.sql"/>
        
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
public class AppTest 
{

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

@BeforeAll
static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("perApp");
}

@AfterAll
static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    emf.close();
}

/**
 * Rigorous Test :-)
 */
@Test
public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
{
   logger.info("In latestFetchQueryTest");
    
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName("John");
    person.setLastName("Doe");
    
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.flush();

    Person p1 = em.find(Person.class, 1);
    assertEquals(p1.getFirstName(), "John");
    em.close();
}
}
```

The pom.xml file is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>come.lets.learn</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-java-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-java-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <hibernate.version>6.4.0.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                        <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                        <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```